# Simulating cost of shuffling while joining tables/dataframes in Spark local mode

Tags: scala, apache-spark, pyspark

I'm trying to simulate burden of data travelling over network while doing dataframes/tables joins with Spark.

I've come up with the following code:

```
object ShuffleSimulation {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val spark = SparkSession.builder()
      .appName("ShuffleSimulation")
      .getOrCreate()

    import spark.implicits._

    // Create some sample data for demonstration
    val data1 = Seq((1, "Alice"), (2, "Bob"), (3, "Charlie"))
    val data2 = Seq((1, 25), (2, 30), (3, 35))

    val df1 = data1.toDF("id", "name")
    val df2 = data2.toDF("id", "age")

    // Perform a join operation with a simulated network latency
    val result = df1.join(df2, "id")

    // Introduce a sleep operation to simulate network latency
    result.foreachPartition { partition =>
      Thread.sleep(1000) // Simulate 1-second network latency
    }

    spark.stop()
  }
}
```

and am wondering if this can be meaningful  while assessing performance of different joins, especially with skewed data (e.g. if this can be useful in assessing salted joins) ?